# ssh login as user and change to root, without sudo

Tags: ssh, su

I have the following task:

- the command has to be run as root on server remotely in bash script over ssh and the command output has to be fetched in variable.
- logging over ssh as root is disabled.
- sudo on server is disabled, so I have to use su.
- EDIT: since I want to make it as automated as possible in bash, the password **has to be** stored inside command

I have Googled for days, but it seems that I cannot find a solution for this.

Solution proposed here: [ssh to server and switch user and change a directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420924/ssh-to-server-and-switch-user-and-change-a-directory)

```
    ssh -t username@hostname "sudo su - otheruser -c \"cd /path/to/directory && command\""
```

does not work because sudo is disabled on server:

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: To switch to another user, you need not use `sudo su - username`, you can plainly use `su - username`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MukeshSaiKumar. Do you really think that I have "Googled for days" just to find "su" command? 
Also have you at least tried this? It is not working!

Comment: `su` is already a setuid binary, so it must be able to switch to any user which you demand it to, with proper authentication. If `su` doesn't seem to be working, check if it has the setuid bit set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps somewhat off topic but this could be achieved with Python and the *paramiko* module:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import time
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('127.0.0.1', port=22, username='user', password='pass')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('su')
time.sleep(0.1) # some enviroment maybe need this.
stdin.write('root_password_goes_here\n')

[ add extra code here to execute a command ]

stdin.flush()
print (stdout.readlines())
ssh.close()
```

It should be noted that storing passwords in script generally is a bad idea from a security perspective. Make sure you have proper permissions set to the script (e.g. chmod 740)

Comment: Thanks! looks nice, I heard about paramiko but I have not used it so far. I will try this. I am always interested in trying some alternative methods.

Comment: I just tried this. I put both regular user and root password. However,  when I put `touch /tmp/test/` into the `[ add extra code here to execute a command ]` line it looks like that /tmp/test is still owned by **regular user** and not root.
I have also tried to do it in one line like this `stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('su root -c "touch /tmp/test"')
stdin.write('password\n')` then /tmp/test is not created.
Any ideas?

Comment: When I'm home later today I will see what I can come up with for you. I should have something similar somewhere that you could use.

Answer (score 5):

Login via SSH (as unprivileged user), then run the command `su` without any arguments to change to the root user. You will need the root password to do this. Then run whatever commands you want to run.
**EDIT:** If you want to do it in one line, you can use the following:
`ssh username@hostname "su -c \"code_here\""`
If this doesn't work, make sure the root password is enabled by running `passwd` as root. This will ask you for a new root password.
**Extra:** To run a command as another user besides root (Please note that this requires the target user's password):
`ssh username@hostname "su - username_of_target -c \"code_here\""`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Giraffer and everyone who voted this up.
Have you at least tried this? It is not working!
it says:  
`user@server ~ $ ssh admin@server "su - root -c \"code_here\""admin@server.com's password: 
su: must be run from a terminal`
Please do not post stuffs that are not checked. Everyone can copy/paste from google!

Comment: I have checked, and it worked. No copy/paste from google here. Did you run `passwd` as root before hand?

Comment: The issue here can be different versions of the su command, as I found on another websites. But then I would need to upgrade su on all servers. Thats why python solution might be better and easier in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can also used paramiko invoke shell command for interactive session.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLKdxIu3-A4

```
import paramiko
from paramiko.channel import Channel
import time
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('ip', port=22, username='non-root', password='non-root-password')

channel:Channel = ssh.invoke_shell()
print(type(channel))
channel_data = str()

while True:
   if channel.recv_ready():
       time.sleep(2)
       channel_data += str(channel.recv(999))
   else:
       continue

   channel.send("whoami\n")
   time.sleep(2)
   channel_data += str(channel.recv(999))

   channel.send("su\n")
   time.sleep(5)
   channel_data += str(channel.recv(999))

   # if "Password" in channel_data:
   channel.send("rootpaasword\n")
   time.sleep(2)
   channel_data += str(channel.recv(999))

   channel.send("whoami\n")
   time.sleep(2)
   channel_data += str(channel.recv(999))

   # channel_data += str(channel.recv(999))
   break


print(channel_data)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the answer that I was looking for and after a lot of hunting and getting fed up with pexpect, I love this. Thanks mate!!

Answer (score 3):

For somewhat less of a security nightmare than putting the root password in a script, you can use a `setuid` executable.

`setuid` executables are run as root, no matter which user executes them.

The main advantage of this is that if someone steals your laptop, they can run `smartctl -a /dev/sda` as root, but otherwise only has your user privileges. Or even less, if you set up a public key with a forced command as mentioned later.

Write a simple C program, `smartctl_wrapper.c`, that simply runs the script or program you need, like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    //depending on your use case, you may want 
    //setuid(0), setgid(0), and/or setegid(0) here
    execl("/full/path/to/smartctl","smartctl","-a","/dev/sda",(char*) NULL);
}
```

And compile it as `gcc smartctl_wrapper.c -o smartctl_wrapper`.

You then make this belong to root, and the group that should be able to run it. These commands should be run as root:

```
chown root:some_group smartctl_wrapper
```

Then make it a `setuid` executable. Also prevent any user from editing it:

```
chmod 4510 smartctl_wrapper
```

This is now an executable that can be run by any member of `some_group` with root permissions, without requiring any password.

Now you can simply run it with ssh:

```
ssh user@server.domain /path/to/smartctl_wrapper
```

If the server allows it, you can set up the ssh connection with a public key to allow connections without a password. You can also use [forced commands](https://binblog.info/2008/10/20/openssh-going-flexible-with-forced-commands/) so that this key isn't good for anything besides running this script.

If the server does not allow it, you can instead make a script with the ssh password in it. In this case, I would highly recommend you make a new user just for this with minimal permissions and a login shell of `/sbin/nologin`.

Alternatively, for your specific use case it may make more sense to avoid running commands as root over `ssh` entirely. You could, for example, schedule this command to run periodically using `cron`. You can edit root's crontab with:

```
su -c crontab -e -u root
```

and adding the line:

```
5 0 * * sun smartctl -a /dev/sda >> /some/path/to/log/some/non/root/user/can/read
```

The line given will run the command once weekly, 5 minutes after midnight on Sunday. You can tweak this to your liking, following the directions in [crontab(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab).

Then you can use `ssh` just to read the logs.

Answer (score 1):

So, after 4 hours of additional web crawling, I finally made it! **Big** thanks for @jeroen-it-nerdbox for giving me insights on this:

Task was to take data from smartctl (which requires root credentials), from server with disabled ssh-root and disabled sudo.
This will of course also work with sudo instead of su.

here is the full workable code in Python with Paramiko implementation.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('rootserver.domain.com', port=22, username='admin', password='adminpass')

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('/bin/su root -c "smartctl -a /dev/sda > /tmp/smartctl_output"', get_pty=True)
stdin.write('rootpass\n')

stdin.flush()
print (stdout.readlines())
ssh.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this simply like this in bash : that simulate human interaction with su. I use it on my automatic remote installers for servers that don't have sudo.

```
sucmd="sh -c 'sleep 3; echo $pass' | script -qc 'su -c ./yourscript.sh root '"

ssh -t -l "$user" "$ipaddress" -p 22 "$sucmd"
```

kind regards,

Comment: (1) What do you mean by “full bash”?  (2) Can you explain this?  Parts of it seem to be unnecessarily complicated. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.